# Why `[\d]` does not work in GNU `grep` with PCRE enabled?

Tags: grep, pcre

I have just noticed that `grep -P '[\d]' <<< 'asdf 1234 asdf'` does not work, while `grep -P '[0-9]' <<< 'asdf 1234 asdf'` works as expected. When `\d` is used outside of square brackets, it works as expected.

Any idea why `[\d]` does not work?

---

Just in case it matters:

```bash
grep (GNU grep) 3.10
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: Use: `grep -P '\d' <<< 'asdf 1234 asdf'`,

Comment: Seems like a bug. `grep -P '[\w]'` works but `grep -P '[\d\w]'` fails.

Comment: @Luuk, that was not the question. `\d` works outside of square brackets. And I know that in this example, the square brackets are redundant.

Comment: @tukusejssirs: Sorry, I fail to understand the problem, see: https://regex101.com/r/o4Aq3i/1

Comment: Also from linux: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmbbp.png

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you seek, but the documentation of the [`-P` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002dP) indicate some behaviour change:

For documentation, refer to https://www.pcre.org/, with these caveats:

> ```
> ‘\d’ matches only the ten ASCII digits (and ‘\D’ matches the complement), regardless of locale. Use ‘\p{Nd}’ to also match
> ```
>
> non-ASCII digits.
>
> ```
> When grep is built with PCRE2 10.42 and earlier, ‘\d’ and ‘\D’ ignore in-regexp directives like ‘(?aD)’ and work like ‘[0-9]’ and
> ```
>
> ‘[^0-9]’ respectively. However, later versions of PCRE2 likely will
> fix this, and the plan is for grep to respect those directives if
> possible.

However, I tried using `[\d]` and it seems to work, at least on Windows and with Git for Windows:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ echo 'a0123c' | grep --color -Po '[\d]+'
0123

$ grep -Po '[\d]' <<< 'asdf 1234 asdf'
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! … I have no idea what PCRE version uses `grep` on my Arch Linux, but `pcre2grep` says it is `10.42`. That said, `When grep is built with PCRE2 10.42 and earlier, ‘\d’ and ‘\D’ ignore in-regexp directives like ‘(?aD)’ and work like ‘[0-9]’ and ‘[^0-9]’ respectively` suggests that `\d` should work like `[0-9]`, but it actually does not. Do you have any idea if `grep` has its implementation of PCRE built-in or does it use a separate library? If a library, which one? … And that `grep@3.0` on MS Windows works as expected, is strange to me.

Comment: `pcre2-config --version` indicate 10.42 too. You could try `--file` (obtain pattern from file) to eliminate any issue that would be from the shell parsing the pattern and returning something else... Even if in bash, `'[\d]'` should be `[\d]`.

Comment: Okay, it really seems like a bug in `grep@3.10` (or `3.7+`, excluding `3.7`). I have upgraded `grep` on Arch Linux to `3.10-1` on 27 March 2023, so it must be why you guys cannot reproduce the bug.

Comment: I have just emailed a bug report to GNU. I hope they resolve it ASAP.